# Any equivalent to QML CalendarStyle in Qt6?

Tags: qtquickcontrols2, qtquickcontrols

I had some QML code using Calendar and CalendarStyle (QtQuick.Controls 1.4 and QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4), and I failed to find anything similar in Qt6.

The old code will obviously not compile with more recent Qt because those imports don't exist anymore.

Comment: A bit late but you find https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-monthgrid.html ? It isn't a control as the calendar in controls 1, but it gives you all the building blocks to implement a similar control and is simpler to customize it.